# select last base status record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I looking for MySQL query to fetch (select) latest max date record with hot status for base in table.
I mean, I want to see all latest distinct base status. `10.4.13-MariaDB`
[mysql db pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVvMG.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE `allcoins` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `base` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quote_currency` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `indic` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `laststatus` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prices` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `indic_label` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `allcoins` (`ID`, `base`, `quote_currency`, `indic`, `status`, `laststatus`, `creation_date`, `prices`, `indic_label`) VALUES
(1, 'ICX', 'BTC', 'adx', 'hot', 'cold', '2020-09-02 15:10:45', '', 'adx 4h'),
(2, 'ICX', 'BTC', 'bbp', 'hot', 'cold', '2020-09-02 15:10:44', '', 'bbp 1h'),
(4, 'ICX', 'BTC', 'stoch_rsi', 'hot', 'hot', '2020-09-02 15:10:42', '', 'adx 4h'),
(5, 'ICX', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'hot', '2020-09-02 15:10:41', '', 'adx 1h'),
(6, 'PIVX', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'cold', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'adx 4h'),
(7, 'IOST', 'BTC', 'ma_ribbon', 'hot', 'neutral', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', ''),
(8, 'IOST', 'BTC', 'bbp', 'cold', 'neutral', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'Bollinger 4 hr'),
(9, 'STEEM', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'cold', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'adx 1h'),
(10, 'NANO', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'cold', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'adx 1h'),
(11, 'VIA', 'BTC', 'bbp', 'hot', 'neutral', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'Bollinger 1H'),
(12, 'BLZ', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'cold', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'adx 1h'),
(13, 'BLZ', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'cold', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'adx 4h'),
(14, 'AE', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'cold', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'adx 1h'),
(15, 'POA', 'BTC', 'adx', 'cold', 'cold', '2020-09-07 18:45:39', '', 'adx 1h');
```

---

sample result:

```
latest status for base=icx when indic=adx is hot
latest status for base=iost when indic=ma_ribbon is hot
we must update all latest base status for indic in web page
```

when i run this query =>[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzXUr.jpg)

```
select DISTINCT max(creation_date), base,status,indic from v2 WHERE indic='rsi' group by base,status
```

---

but i need like this => [result final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V44Sd.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of the results you want.

Comment: Are you sure you are running MyISAM?

Comment: @O.Jones Ok. i do it . thanks

Comment: @TheImpaler i using xaamp with default config

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you want max(creation_date) grouped by status and base can use this:

```
select max(creation_date), base,status from allcoins group by base,status;
```

Comment: thanks but not good for me

Comment: please note a sample result based on your sample data

Comment: latest status for base=icx when indic=adx is hot

Comment: show all result for all sample table entry as a table not like a line !

Comment: Done! thanks in advanced.